# NodeJS accessing 'un-prefixed' route names (e.g. "/home") from within 'prefixed' routes (e.g. "/something/about" ) causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is with regards to routing. I am trying to navigate to a route which does not contain a prefix, from a route which does contain one, but it is appending the current routes prefix to it automatically.

I know it sounds confusing, but take a look at this code snippet:

First Route

```js
app.get('/something', () => {
...route code here
})
```

Another route accessible from the '/something' route which builds up on it

```js
app.get('/something/about', () => {
...route code here
})
```

A route which does not include '/something'

```js
app.get('/home', () => {
...route code here
})
```

So the problem is that when I've navigated into the routes prefixed with `/something` and I click on an anchor to take me to the `/home` route for example, it appends `/something/` to it automatically and consequently it errors since there is no route for `/something/home`, there is only a route for `/home`.

So I need something which looks at the exact path on the anchor tag, something like `exact` from VueJS, how do you do that for NodeJS without it appending the 'prefix'?

```html
<a href="home" exact >Home</a>
```

Please assist.

Comment: The problem isn't your node code, it's the link's URL. You need `href="/about"` instead. The leading slash makes the browser append the relative path to the domain name instead of the current location.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. What a sneaky bug! Thank you Chris, that fixed it.